# Split single row columns into multiple columns in Hive

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have a Hive table like this

```
ID1 Name1 ID2 Name2 ID3 Name3....
1   ABC   2   MNP   3   XYZ
11  LMP   12  PLL   13  UIP
```

This table may have any no. of columns pair(i.e. ID and Name)

I need to convert the above table into a new Hive table having only 2 columns ID and Name like below

```
ID  Name
1   ABC
2   MNP
3   XYZ
11  LMP
12  PLL
13  UIP
```

Please suggest how can I achieve this in Hive.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select  explode(map(*)) as (id,name)
from    mytable
;
```

---

```
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
|  1 | ABC  |
|  2 | MNP  |
|  3 | XYZ  |
| 11 | LMP  |
| 12 | PLL  |
| 13 | UIP  |
+----+------+
```

Comment: I have updated the question.. The table will have repeated set of 4 columns instead of 2. Map is not working for more than 2 columns. Please suggest any other solution.

Comment: Thanks Dudu
I have accepted your Answer.. Will post another question.

Comment: please check (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44039492/hadoop-hive-convert-single-row-columns-into-multiple-rows-in-hive)