# Hadoop-Hive | Convert single row columns into multiple rows in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have a Hive table like this

```
 Created_date   ID1 Name1 Age1 Gender1 Name2 ID2 Age2 Gender2 ID3 Name3  Age3 Gender3....
  2014-02-01    1   ABC   21    M      MNP    2  22   F       3   XYZ    25   M
  2015-06-06    11  LMP   31    F      PLL   12  42   M       13  UIP    37   F
```

This table may have any no. of repeated set of the 4 columns pair. The sequence of these 4 columns is also not fix and there may be 1 or 2 more columns which are not repeated like created_date

I need to convert the above table into a new Hive table having only 4 columns ID, Name, Age and Gender like below. I dont need created_date column in my result table.

```
ID  Name  Age Gender
1   ABC   21  M
2   MNP   22  F
3   XYZ   25  M
11  LMP   31  F
12  PLL   42  M
13  UIP   37  F
```

Please suggest how can I achieve this in Hive.

Comment: you can use unionall but for this you should known how many column do you have

Comment: No. of columns is not fixed..

Comment: Ankit, the number of columns in a specific hive table is always fixed.

Comment: I see that in your example `Name2` comes before `ID2`. Is it intentional?

Comment: Can `ID` be trusted to be unique?

Comment: Yes Dudu
the sequence of columns may be different 
I intentionally kept it different

Comment: By No. of column I mean, for one client the table may have 3 sets of these columns and for other it may be 4,5 or anything else..So I just want a generic solution which can be used for any client having any no. of set of repeated columns.

Comment: The number of columns cannot differ between clients. Some of the columns might hold NULL values, but that is a different story. Please change your example to reflect that actual use-case.

Comment: It changes in our use case :(
The table will have comments, user who commented, time of comment etc.
So no. of comments varies for each client.

Comment: Ankit, This does not make much sense. Please change your example to reflect that actual use-case.

Answer (score 3):

```
select  inline
        (
            array
            (
                struct(ID1,Name1,Age1,Gender1)
               ,struct(ID2,Name2,Age2,Gender2)
               ,struct(ID3,Name3,Age3,Gender3)
             )
        ) as (ID,Name,Age,Gender)

 from   mytable
```

---

```
+----+------+-----+--------+
| id | name | age | gender |
+----+------+-----+--------+
|  1 | ABC  |  21 | M      |
|  2 | MNP  |  22 | F      |
|  3 | XYZ  |  25 | M      |
| 11 | LMP  |  31 | F      |
| 12 | PLL  |  42 | M      |
| 13 | UIP  |  37 | F      |
+----+------+-----+--------+
```

Answer (score -1):

Your problem can be solved using Hive UDTF. User defined tabular function(UDTF) works on one row as input and returns multiple rows as output.

For example:

We have a file in which we have multiple records. Each record contains a list of customer, merchant1, merchant2. We want to get a list of all the distinct customers associated with a customer.

```
Sample Input: 
Cust1, Merchant1, Merchant2
Cust2, Merchant1, Merchant2

Expected Output
Cust1, Merchant1
Cust1, Merchant2
Cust2, Merchant1
Cust2, Merchant2
```

Now you can write a UDTF named **Explode** that would get the expected output and can be used in a query like :

```
Select Explode(customer, firstMerchant, secondMerchant) 
AS (cust, merchant) 
from Merchants
```

You can refer :
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/DeveloperGuide+UDTF

Comment: How is this a table if you dont know the schema ?

Comment: If your schema is fixed i.e , if you know how many columns a record would have at max, still you can split the records